# UIScrollView positioning in a View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've got a problem with the position of an UIScrollView. In a tableview I have some items and on tap each item has a detailview. When I open the app the tableview shows up and when I select an item , in the detailview I have a scrollview. The problem is that it doesn't show where it supposed to be. It appears lower in the view, also I have a small menu on the bottom that doesn't show. But if I access the main menu of the app where I have my tableview along with other views and then I go to the tableview and tap on an item....the scrollview in the detailview is in the right position and also the menu on the bottom is visible. Any ideas why this happens? I'm attaching two images to see what I'm talking about:

Here's the first image with the wrong position:

[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img689/3834/t5ek.png]

and the second one with the scrollview and the menu positioned where they should be.

[image: http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/2876/oje2.png]

The scrollview size is dynamic because I'm using an UITextView inside that changes its content.

```
- (void)configureScrollView{

CGRect textViewFrame = self.ingredientsTextView.frame;
textViewFrame.size = [self.ingredientsTextView contentSize];
self.ingredientsTextView.frame = textViewFrame;

CGRect contentViewFrame = self.contentView.frame;
contentViewFrame.size.height = textViewFrame.origin.y+textViewFrame.size.height+10.0f;
self.contentView.frame = contentViewFrame;

[self.scrollView setContentSize:contentViewFrame.size];

self.ingredientsTextView.editable=NO;
self.ingredientsTextView.scrollEnabled=NO;

//enable zoomIn
self.scrollView.delegate=self;
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=1;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=7;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try calling "configureScrollView" method from viewdidAppear.

Comment: Same result unfortunately